# Override Ribbon Save Button functionality for a specific page layout?

Tags: 2010, ribbon, page-layout, publishing-page

Is there a way to override Ribbon Save Button functionality in publishing page of specific page layout? My intention is not to override it for all publishing pages but to limit it to specific page layout?

Answer (score 1):

please create a javascript function **PreSaveAction()** in your page layout. In presave action will fire when you click on save button. You can write any javascript code in this function which needs to be perform just before saving the page.

This is working fine in sharepoint list, but I have not tried in publishing page

Answer (score 0):

You could a create a new control deriving from the original, and add it to a custom masterpage.

I don't know if it's wise to do this in a page layout because the ribbon is on the masterpage.
jQuery would be a solution here, you could just add a script in a head content placeholder on your pagelayout to enable it there only.

Answer (score 0):

You may block the native SharePoint javascript when you click the button, and then run your code. See here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38725815/sharepoint-2013-save-button-in-the-ribbon-cancel-saving-if-form-not-valid/38795197#38795197